# How to deserialize a JSON return into an array of objects from a RestSharp call to an API?

Tags: c#, json, restsharp, json-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a JSON return from a RestSharp call to an API.

This is a C# console application. Here is my code so far:

```
using System;
using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Authenticators;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using RestSharp.Deserializers;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TwilioTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01");
            var request = new RestRequest("Accounts/{{Account Sid}}/Messages.json", Method.GET);
            request.AddParameter("To", "{{phone number}}");
            request.AddParameter("From", "{{phone number}}");
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("{{account sid}}", "{{auth token}}");
            var response = client.Execute(request);
            var jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);
            Console.WriteLine(jsonResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

The response is a JSON-formatted list of messages, with keys including `"to"`, `"from"`, `"body"`, and `"status"`. Here's sort of what that looks like:

```
{
  "to": "{{phone number}}",
  "from": "{{phone number}}",
  "body": "Sent from your Twilio trial account - Message 1!",
  "status": "delivered"
},
{
  "to": "{{phone number}}",
  "from": "{{phone number}}",
  "body": "Sent from your Twilio trial account - Message 2",
  "status": "delivered"
},
```

I want to turn that into an array of `Message` objects, with a `Message` class that looks like this:

```
class Message
{
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

I've been looking around for how to turn JSON into objects and found this page: http://blog.atavisticsoftware.com/2014/02/using-restsharp-to-deserialize-json.html. The third example on the page is along the lines of what I want.

I made some changes to the program and now it looks like this:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // same as above until this point
            ...
            var response = client.Execute(request);
            JsonDeserializer deserial = new JsonDeserializer();
            var messageList = deserial.Deserialize<List<Message>>(response);
            foreach (Message element in messageList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("To: {0}", element.To);
                Console.WriteLine("From: {0}", element.From);
                Console.WriteLine("Body: {0}", element.Body);

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

However, `messageList` is empty when I run the program. What am I missing to turn the JSON response into a list of objects? The [RestSharp Documentation](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization) makes it look fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know much about RestSharp, but you can get the response content string like that :

```
var responseContent = client.Execute(request).Content;
```

And use [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to deserialize your json string :

```
JObject jsonResponse = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);
var messageList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Message>>(jsonResponse["messages"].ToString()‌​);
```

Comment: I tried this out, and responseContent is a string that looks like `{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" ...}`. When the program hits the DeserializeObject line, I get a JsonSerializationException: "Cannot deserialize the current JSON object into type because the type requires a JSON array to deserialize correctly."  I've tried a few things I've found online to convert a JSON string to array, but keep running into errors. Does there need to be a property in the message class for every key in the JSON to deserialize correctly?

Comment: can you post the json?

Comment: I figured it out - the json response had a lot of properties, and one of those was the list of messages. So when I tried to deserialize the entire response into a list of Message objects, it gave an error, since it wasn't a JSON response of messages.

Comment: This is the code that worked: ```var response = client.Execute(request);
            JObject jsonResponse = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);
            var messageList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Message>>(jsonResponse["messages"].ToString());
```

Comment: @jmk22 ok because the body content is wrapped into the response.... I'll edited the answer